# Vi buffer contents stay on-screen after using screen commands

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, xterm

In shell terminal,

```
echo $TERM --- prints xterm
```

Now I do `vi somedoc` and `exit`, vi contents disappear from the shell screen and the shell's previously run commands are visible. So far, all good.

Now I run `screen ssh localhost` and do `Ctrl-A, c` to put the ssh session in the background.

```
echo $TERM --- prints screen
```

Now I do `vi somedoc` and `exit`, vi buffer' contents occupy the entire screen and the bash shell prompt goes to the last line in the screen. This makes the terminal no longer usable as I need to do `clear` after entering and exiting vim.

I tried to do, `export TERM=xterm` and see if exiting vi clears the buffer contents from terminal, but it has no effect

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of xterm called the alternate screen.  Whether an application uses the alternate screen is controlled by escape sequences.  Normally those are combined with the terminal's initialization and reset sequences (`smcup` and `rmcup` in terminfo, `ti` and `te` in termcap).

The xterm program (unlike other programs which may emulate xterm) has an X resource setting `titeInhibit` (named for the termcap feature) which tells it to suppress the switching to/from alternate screen.  However, you are most likely able to control this by choosing (or modifying) the terminfo description so that it does the switching as you want.

For more information, see the xterm FAQ *[Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)*